# laravel file upload form with dropzone.js

Tags: php, forms, laravel, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone.js script to upload images in Laravel framework, everything is working after I upload an image, but I can't do that images move to folder only after submit button.

I was reading documentation, forums, everywhere it's written to add code to dropzone.js file
but it's still not working, it's just move image immediately after uploading it

I want to do that images would move to given path only after submit button is clicked. Not after it's ulpoaded.

Dropzone.js

```
  function __guardMethod__(obj, methodName, transform) {
      if (typeof obj !== 'undefined' && obj !== null && typeof obj[methodName] === 'function') {
        return transform(obj, methodName);
      } else {
        return undefined;
      }
    };

    /*
   Code below is that I need to add
    */

     Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {

        // Prevents Dropzone from uploading dropped files immediately
        autoProcessQueue: false,

        init: function() {
          var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-all")
              myDropzone = this; // closure

          submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
            myDropzone.processQueue(); // Tell Dropzone to process all queued files.
          });

          // You might want to show the submit button only when 
          // files are dropped here:
          this.on("addedfile", function() {
            // Show submit button here and/or inform user to click it.
          });

        }
      };
```

PHP form

```
</head>
<body>
     <h3>Image upload</h3>

 {!! Form::open(array('url'=>'imgUpload', 'method' => 'PUT',
     'name'=>'product_images', 'id'=>'myImageDropzone', 'class'=>'dropzone', 'files'=>true )) !!}

      <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit-all" value="Click Me">
    {!! Form::close() !!}  

</body>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="\js\dropzone.js"></script>
</html>
```

imageController, I tried to add isset but still same problem.

```
 class imageController extends Controller
    {
        public function index(){
            return view('imgUpload');
        }

        public function uploadFiles(Request $request){
            if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
            {
            if ($request->hasFile('file'))
            {
                $imageFile = $request->file('file');
                $imageName = uniqid().$imageFile->getClientOriginalName();
                $imageFile->move(public_path('uploads'),$imageName);
            }
            }
            return view('imgUpload');
        }

    }
```

Comment: so you want to add images ..as soon as you drop the image ..am i correct ?

Comment: no, this is working right now, what I want to do that images would move to given path only after submit button is clicked. Not after its ulpoaded

Comment: where is it uploading now...what is the difference between uploading and submit..??

Comment: $imageFile->move(public_path('uploads'),$imageName);

the difference is that I want that the user could take a look at uploaded images before submit